# Adding items to Gnome-fallback menu (13.10)

Tags: gnome-classic

I want to add new items to the applications menu in Gnome-session-fallback:
I open the edit with alt-rt-click, select the submenu where I want the new item. and add the details to the dialogue box. Unfortunately, it puts the new item in "other" WHICH IS NOT WHERE I WANT IT. There is no cut-and-paste facility to move the item. It is stuck where I don't want it! Is there a way to sort this out? Most of the items in "other" really ought to be under a more useful heading anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete it then add it again, but it is better to use MenuLibre:

1. Install it:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install menulibre
   ```
2. Launch it, then use the arrow buttons in the lower left corner to move your custom menu entry:

[image: organizing menu]